# Can Intel Pin redirect the program execution?

Tags: intel, intel-pin

Does Pin has the ability to redirect the execution on a wrong path? For example, if I have a program like:

```
if(expr)
{
    // Do something
}
```

where `expr` evaluates to `true`, can I use Pin to force the execution to NOT take the `if` branch? If yes, what Pin APIs can I use to do this?

Comment: No, PIN works by adding instructions to code, so only the architectural path is observable, not mis-speculations.  For the same reason that code in not-taken `if` blocks doesn't run in normal programs.